# Default facebook application gets called eventhough I am using facebook sdk in my aplication

Tags: android

I am using facebook sdk in my application. It is working fine when there is no facebook app installed in my mobile.But when I download and install facebook app from playstore, my application facebook is redirected to facebook app which I installed from playstore.

How can I restrict that my app should use my sdk which I used in  my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is by default. If you have facebook app in your device then that app will be redirected but if you dont have then facebook webview will be called. You cant change it.

So if you want webview then uninstall facebook app.

Comment: I am using facebook sdk, I am getting login dialog, I am not using webview.still my application is redirected to default facebook app.

Comment: Remove that app. then automatically you will be redirected to webview

Comment: I know that,but our application should work independently eventhough there are facebook apps

Comment: that cant be done as facebook app have higher priority so it will take all information from facebook app. but i dont know what problem you are facing with facebook app.